# Who was responsible for the murder of Elizabeth Short, AKA the Black Dahlia? Was it a doctor who was formerly married to a police captain's daughter?

Tags: united-states, crime

I read there was a fairly good case for such a doctor by the name of *Patrick S. O'Reilly, *who had strong sadistic tendencies, and a missing pectoral, which fitted the lacerations on her body, and relation to police (he was formerly married to a daughter of a police captain), which could have greatly assisted in a cover-up. Also were there any murders with similar modus operandi and patterns in adjacent years/locations?

Comment: Interesting though it may be, no one on this forum can answer this question or it *wouldn't be* an unsolved murder.

Comment: @user2448131 I tend to disagree. I think my answer below covers it. To paraphrase: "Nobody knows. Here's the evidence, such as it is. Make up your own mind."

Comment: @  sempaiscuba My comment is to explain my reason for voting to close this particular question.  You agree with me there is no answer, so by definition it is a 'bad question' for the forum as only opinion or non-answers can be replies. You might check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98197/should-users-be-penalized-for-answering-bad-questions) meta discussion. I like (mostly) your answer style and information level, so I have not downvoted the answer, but expressed my opinion on the quality of the question.

Comment: @user2448131 Fair point. I've opened a [discussion](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3469/is-a-question-with-no-known-answer-really-a-bad-question) on Meta, and I hope you'll contribute.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is "Nobody knows who murdered Elizabeth Short".

A lot of theories have been advanced over the years, and [several suspects have been named](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Dahlia#Suspects). [Patrick S. O'Reilly](http://blackdahlia.web.unc.edu/patrick-s-oreilly/) is certainly one of the names that has been advanced as a suspect, but it seems that it was actually George Hodel who topped the LAPD’s list of suspects at the time of the crime. Hodel's son became a detective in the LAPD and has published much of the 'evidence' that [he believes confirms his father's guilt](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/may/26/black-dahlia-murder-steve-hodel-elizabeth-short).

As for other [similar or related murders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Dahlia#Theories_and_possibly-related_murders), a few have been suggested, but none with entirely convincing evidence to support the link.

You can read a lot of the background information about the case on the [Black Dahlia website](http://blackdahlia.web.unc.edu/), and the [unclassified FBI files](https://vault.fbi.gov/search?SearchableText=Black%20dahlia) are certainly worth reading too.

Comment: latest FBI secret recordings admit the suspect Hodel most likely never met or knew short, and that while he was known as a womanizer, he was a very weak suspect from the start.

Comment: @Bak1139 Sadly that seems to be true of most of those identified as suspects. The unclassified files available online on the FBI vault are worth reading (I've added a link to the answer) if you're interested in the case, although I should say you probably won't end up any wiser about who actually killed Elizabeth Short..

Comment: most of the other suspects appear weak or unrelated, this guy had a strong sadistic tendency, had already almost beat to death a woman once, and was in ties with the police.....It is strange he was not arrested.